# Sencha touch 2 : getting item index in itemTpl

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In the documentation of XTemplate, {#} can be used to get the current array index.

When I use it in the itemTpl of an xlist, I always get 1 instead of the index:

```
    {
        xtype: 'list',
            store: 'myStore',
            itemTpl:new Ext.XTemplate(
                 '<tpl for=".">',
                      '<div>Item n°{#1}</div>',
                 '</tpl>'
            ),          
    }
```

always produces "Item n°1" even if my store contains several items.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you're using a **Ext.List** which fetchs data from a **Ext.data.Store**, not an Array, so XTemplate processes only 1 item at one time. That's why the {#} (also called xindex) always return 1.

A suggest to work-around this is to set manually the index of items in your store once it's loaded, like this: (listener for your Store)

```
listeners: {
  load: function(store, records){
    store.each(function(record, index){
      record.set('index', index);
    },
    store
  );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but then won't I have problems when my store is dynamically changed (deleting and inserting items) ?

Comment: that's also able to be done through `addrecords`, `removerecords`, `updaterecords` or simply, `refresh()` event.

Comment: I found another way, because one has to be careful if doing this in updaterecords, you will enter in a infinite recursion...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I came up with this:

```
itemTpl: [
           '<div class="item">' +
              'Number {[this.getIndex()]}' +
           '</div>',
           {
              getIndex: function() {
                  return document.getElementsByClassName('item').length + 1;
              }
           }
         ]
```

I prefer this solution than adding extra properties to the store.

And btw, you don't need to put `<tpl for="."></tpl>` in itemTpl, it's implicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is "as designed" since you are not looping on a record/array here.  The template is instantiated once for each element of the store.

See also http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179728-Autonumber-in-Template-in-DataView

Comment: Thanks... So if there's no way to do numbering in a xlist... Strange in my opinion...

Comment: `itemTpl` works with `data` which is an array. So the _looping on a array_ doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, ran into this thread & thought there should be a better solution.
After looking into the code of DataView, I noticed the following overridable method :

```
prepareData: function(data, index, record) {
    return data;
}
```

So there is an index, you only need to add a little override  :).
I prefer this quick solution, adding the index to my dataobject and overriding a method which is provided for overriding purposes.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.dataview.DataView', {
    override: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',

    prepareData: function(data, index, record) {
        if(Ext.isObject(data)) {
            data.xindex = index + 1;
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```