# Sencha Touch Extjs itemTpl # inside if tag

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

**HOW TO USE {#} INSIDE AN IF TAG IN ITEMTPL?**

So lets say I want to do something different just for the first item in my itemTpl, I would think some of this should work :

```
'<tpl if="# &lt; 1">',  // NOT WORKING
```

OR

```
'<tpl if="{#} &lt; 1">', // NOT WORKING
```

OR

```
'<tpl if="\'#\' &lt; 1">', // NOT WORKING
```

although I can do:

```
itemTpl : '{x}' //print indexes
```

Comment: This question may be similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10075394/814416

Comment: In fact it is not. since the question you refer states that he can not get the index for a list. I do get the index (I guess Sencha did some update) but won't work inside of an if tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with

```
<tpl if="xindex === 0"> Only show in first item </tpl>
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate